# How to programmatically add, remove, or block people on Steam through a button

Tags: steam-web-api

There are many sites such as [www.tf2outpost.com](http://www.tf2outpost.com) and [www.bazaar.tf](http://www.bazaar.tf) where users can add other steam users through the click of a button. How exactly do you accomplish this? There's nothing in the web API that shows you how to add friends.

**EDIT:** I have found this code: `steam://friends/add/some_steam_id` Can you modify this code to block/remove people if you have their steam id?

Answer (score 5):

All that URL does is ask your locally installed Steam client to add a fried of the id matching the number after `/add/`. So if you have another users steam id you can add them by putting their id in that URL like this: `steam://friends/add/your_new_friends_id`

you can try this yourself by just pasting the url in most any internet browser and steam will popup with a message saying "Your New Friend has been added to your friends list"

Currently the `friends` command accepts the following subcommands:

- `add/<id>`
  Adds user with specified id number
- `friends/<id>`
  Shows list of users with whom you recently played
- `joinchat/<id>`
  Joins a chat with a specified id number
- `message/<id>`
  Send a message
- `players`
  Shows table of recent players you've played with
- `settings/hideoffline`
  Toggle offline friends from friends list
- `settings/showavatars`
  Toggle avatars in friends list
- `settings/sortbyname`
  Sorts friends list by name
- `status/away`
  Sets status as away
- `status/busy`
  Sets status as busy
- `status/trade`
  Sets status as looking to trade
- `status/play`
  Sets status as looking to play
- `status/offline`
  Sets status as offline
- `status/online`
  Sets status as online

It appears there currently is no command (at least not public) for blocking/removing people. Such a command would be fairly useless, and would allow for... mischief. You should just manually remove/block people you no longer wish to be friends with; there would be no convenience added from being able to do this from a browser. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

See the [Steam Browser API documentation](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_browser_protocol) for complete details about the `friends` command and other commands.

P.S. its probably a good idea to avoid posting other peoples steam user ids here.

Comment: Ok, then can I block/remove people using a similar method?

Comment: @BradAllred Sorry for reviving old topic, but how do you launch those? I suppose you could use Desktop to open URL in default browser, but is there more elegant way doing it?

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino not sure exactly what you are asking. they are just URLs so its a bit dependent on how your OS deals with that. If you open them in a browser your browser is (likely) going to hand it back to the OS, which should result in steam handling the URL. Making a URL "shortcut" is again something that is (probably) OS specific.

Comment: Works fine on browser, can't get the deeplink/browser protocol to work on Android though.'